# "EntityType 'SelectListItem' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType" when bind checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist

I want to bind checkboxlist in mvc.

I have done code also but in that I am getting the error when run the site.

Here is my code,

I have created model

```
public class StaffRegistration
{
    public IList<SelectListItem> WeekEndDay { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my DBContext

```
public class TableContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<StaffRegistration> staff { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
public class StaffRegistrationController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Weekend()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> names = new List<SelectListItem>();
        names.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Monday", Value = "1" });
        names.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Tuesday", Value = "2" });
        names.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Wednesday", Value = "3" });
        names.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Thrusday", Value = "4" });
        names.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Friday", Value = "5" });
        names.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Saturday", Value = "6" });
        names.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Sunday", Value = "7" });
        staff.WeekEndDay = names;

        return View(staff);
    }
}
```

And finally here is my view

```
@model SchoolWebApplication.Models.StaffRegistration
@foreach (var names in @Model.WeekEndDay)
{
    var checkBoxId = "chk" + names.Value;
    var tdId = "td" + names.Value;
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="20px">
                <input type="checkbox" 

            id="@checkBoxId" 

            class="chkclass" value="@names.Value" />
            </td>
            <td id="@tdId"  width="100px">
                @names.Text
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

So, this is code for binding the checkboxlist of weekend but when I am running site in local at that time it showing the error i.e. :

```
"EntityType 'SelectListItem' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
SelectListItems: EntityType: EntitySet 'SelectListItems' is based on type 'SelectListItem' that has no keys defined."
```

For more clear I have updated the image also. Please review it.

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: Your `WeekEndDay` needs to be part of a view model, not the data model. But a `IList<SelectListItem>` property is not relevant for your view anyway

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it... Can you describe it... With some code...

Comment: What is it your trying to do here (your code makes no sense). What do you want to store in the database? - a collection of days associated with a `StaffRegistration`? - in which case what is your 1-many table for storing those values?

Comment: Now what I want to do...?

Comment: I assumed `StaffRegistration` as a viewmodel instead of concrete data model, certainly you can't use `DbSet` from `SelectListItem` object - since `DbSet` only support model class containing standard value types & string. Create data model based from database objects and bind to `DbSet`, then you can assign passed viewmodel properties to data model.